# How can I find question that have newly assigned bounties?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, sorting

Assume there are 150 questions featured/with bounty, and I have read them all. An hour later I come back, and now there are 152. Currently, it seems I need to scroll through and read all 152 to find the two new ones - which gets *very* boring after the fourhundredthirtysecond time...

Is there a way to find the new ones right away?

'Sort by newest' would do it, but there seems to be no way to do that within the bounty list.

Comment: Newest are always at the end